# Using SoX for noise reduction on AAC in an MPEG-4 container

Tags: linux, yum, ffmpeg, sox

Here are my business needs:

1. Server receives a noisy `noisy.m4a` file
2. Server creates a noise-reduced `noiseless.m4a` file for further processing

I want this noise-reduction to be as fast as possible; hence, I'd like to avoid using `ffmpeg` to go from `.m4a` to `.mp3` for SoX noise profiling, and back to `.m4a` after SoX outputs a `.mp3`.

Is it possible to compile and configure SoX for AAC support out of the box? My system is on Amazon Linux with the `yum` package manager - as simple a setup is of course, preferred to a laborious one.

If however, it is absolutely essential to couple `ffmpeg` with `sox`, then it'd be great to have a piped shell-command that avoids creating a bunch of scratchpad/temporary files.

Thanks for your time!